# enterprise Architect export big diagram

Tags: export, diagram, enterprise-architect

Hello i'm trying to export a diagram with more than 3000 tables, but, when it generates a diagram with BMP show a error below....
Could someone help me with this??

[image: Click to see the error]

Comment: What in earth are you doing with a diagram containing 3000+ tables? Wallpaper? And have you tried playing with the memory limits as indicated by the error?

Comment: lol, i'm generating a documentation for us about database.  i don't found the menu tools in version 13 of EA.....

Comment: See ribbon Start | Workspace | Preferences for the options dialog in v13

Comment: I tried, and use 512mb, but don't worked =/, any sugestion?

Comment: create useful smaller diagrams instead of the insane 3000+ table diagram.

Comment: Try to set the value to 1 TB and if your machine is too small, buy a bigger one. 3000 boxes means about 55*55 boxes of 3*5cm (at minimum) resulting in a 165*275 cm paper. Well done.